# Civ 5 poland in open borders

Tags: civilization-5

Hi guys I have granted Poland to walk over my empire ( open borders ) and now they have a big army in my country and it keeps staying on that exact spot and on next turns they change spots but go back again to the spot. What's going on? Are they plotting an attack?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you two have at least a neutral relationship. If he is friendly towards you, it is more likely that he is moving his troops to attack one of your neighbours instead you. Check his diplomatic relationship with others. It is also possible that he wants to back stab you, but it is somewhat unlikely, because he would have done this before entering you border anyways.